# Show the exact header PHP made for HTTP requests?

Tags: php, http

Is there a way to get the exact Headers sent by function like `file_get_contents()` or `get_headers()` ?

like

```
get_headers('http://google.it');
echo php_get_request_headers();  //> ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this issue once so what i use is a proxy such as `fiddler` http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

```
$default_opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"HEAD",
    'proxy'=>"tcp://localhost:8888"
  )
);

$default = stream_context_set_default($default_opts);
$headers = get_headers('http://google.com');

var_dump($headers);
```

It capture all the request  sent by this script because of the `stream_context_set_default`  .. this would work for `file_get_contents` , `fopen` etc.

Comment: `PHP` did not give me any cheap one i know of ... do you have any better idea ???

Comment: No, I don't think there is any other solution

Comment: Ok ... i would do a little research and come back if i find one ... i don't give up easily